# Any difference between "under many minutes" and "in many minutes" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, prepositions, word-meaning

I feel like there is a slight difference between "**under many minutes**" and "**in many minutes**" in the following sentence, but I cannot tell what or why. Could anyone help, please?

**The context is:**

Elizabeth has just told her mother that she has been engaged with Darcy.

> When her mother went up to her dressing-room at night, she followed
>   her, and made the important communication. Its effect was most
>   extraordinary, for, on first hearing it, Mrs. Bennet sat quite still,
>   and unable to utter a syllable. **Nor was it under many, many minutes,
>   that she could comprehend what she heard, though not in general
>   backward to credit what was for the advantage of her family, or that
>   came in the shape of a lover to any of them.** She began at length to
>   recover, to fidget about in her chair, get up, sit down again, wonder,
>   and bless herself.
>
> *from Pride & Prejudice*

Comment: _Under many minutes_ is an unusual usage. I don't know if it was common in Jane Austen's day, but today we would say _for many minutes_ in this context.

Comment: not that I could recall any.

Comment: You can't recall any what?

Comment: sorry for the confusion. I mean it's the first time I saw the author use "under" in this novel, if I remember correctly.

Comment: sorry to disturb you again. but would you bother to take a look of the comments under the Answer. do you agree that "backward" means "Unwilling to act; reluctant; shy."?  if you have time.

Comment: Yes. She was not usually slow to believe anything that would be to her family's advantage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Nor was it under many, many minutes, that she could comprehend what she heard

It means that not less than many minutes passed before she could comprehend.
  (It took her quite a while to understand.)

So, "in many minutes" misses the "less than" meaning.

> though not in general backward to credit what was for the advantage of her family,

though usually, she was not slow to believe things that were of advantage,
(She was quick to believe those things.).

Comment: I found in dictionary that backward could mean"(of a person) having learning difficulties”,or "behind in time, progress, or development"; but I can't find its meaning of "slow". I wonder which explanation is more close to "slow"?

Comment: @user86301 The sense here is similar to that in American Heritage Dictionary "3. Unwilling to act; reluctant; shy."  She was not reluctant to believe something she thought to be to her advantage, so she was quick to believe it.

Comment: thanks. this  is really out of my expectation. I had  seen it but never thought it was right.  I had thought even  "behind in time, progress, or development" is a better choice than " Unwilling to act; reluctant; shy."

Comment: @user86301 I think this writing is challenging even to a native English speaker, partly because it was written so long ago, and partly because the writer seems to like writing complicated things. Good luck with it.

Comment: I suddenly remembered  why I did not chose that explanation; because Mrs. Bennet is certainly never a "shy" person; but once get rid of "shy", the rest---"Unwilling to act; reluctant" does make sense now.

Comment: In British conversation, if someone is noticeably **not** shy, we can say they are "not backward about coming forward", especially, but not exclusively, in connection with approaching potential sexual or dating partners.

Comment: @user86301 Yes, it's saying she is not usually backward = not shy = not reluctant. Don't miss the negation.

Comment: Old British joke: Woman (boarding a ship): I want to speak to the captain! Sailor: He's forrard, Miss. Woman: That's all right, I've been out with medical students.